# How to avoid input parameters appended to the browser url in angular2 routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the routing, when we pass some value as paramters from one component to another, the passed parameters values gets appended to the browser url... is there any way it can be avoided? [image]

In the example from snapshot attached "Administrator" is the username which I am passing from home.ts component

My routing is as follows

```
[![export const routes: RouterConfig = \[
    { path: '', component: Login },
    { path: 'login', component: Login },
    { path: 'Home/:userName', component: Home },
    ...HOME_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    }
\]

export const HOME_ROUTER_PROVIDERS: RouterConfig = \[
    {
        path: 'Home/:userName',
        component: Home,
        children: \[

            { path: 'Dashboard1', component: Dashboard1 },
            { path: 'Dashboard2', component: Dashboard2 },
            ....
    }
\]][1]][1]
```

My home.ts where I do the navigate.route to pass the parameters

```js
export class Home {
        userName: any;
        constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
            console.log("In constructor of Home");
            activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
                this.userName = params['userName']
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The routers job is to reflect the state to the browsers URL bar and the URL to the state. If you don't wan't parts of it reflected in the URL bar, then don't maintain this state using the router. In addition to @MadhuRanjan s answer see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may create a `UserService` using it in your Login component you may set some variable which decides if the logged in user is administrator or not.

And when your Home component is routed you may read role value from `UserService` and do stuff using the value.

Comment: This will cause error when refreshing a browser. How can we avoid that situation?

Comment: A general answer to the title of the question migth be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377565/angular-4-router-how-to-not-display-parameters-in-the-url-bar