# Routing with hidden path

Tags: angular, routes

I have this basic route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: WidgetComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'P3',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'NN',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

and it works pretty fine. When i navigate to `.../p3` it load my component.

Now, the url that load isn't just this one above. But something like this:

`localhost:4200/P3?p1=hello&p2=world`

But it still works fine in `serve`.

When I build the App and publish it, I have this problem: by navigating directly to `localhost:4200/P3?p1=hello&p2=world` the server response is a `This page cannot be found on the server`, and I managed to understand that is the `P3` the problem. So I've added the `HashLocationStrategy` in my module:

`{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }`,

so now my url is this :

`<server>/#/P3?p1=hello&p2=world`

and this solved my problem.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking, is it possible to hide just the `P3` in the url? I saw on the documentation that there is 
`skipLocationChange: true` to set to the route's `NavigationExtras` but It doesn't satisfied me.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I do not understand the problem: so you basically want to have the same URL while navigating through the application? You may want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47824260/2275011

Comment: I just want to hide on the url the string `P3` declared on `path` in my route config

Comment: Just check this answer: it seems that it is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377565/angular-4-router-how-to-not-display-parameters-in-the-url-bar/47824260#47824260

Answer (score 1):

The default location strategy `PathLocationStrategy` which is most acceptable one. This is the `default` `strategy` in Angular and takes advantage of new `HTML5` API called `pushstate` (from the HTML5 history API). 
Adding `#` into the url it makes little noisy. So avoid `HashLocationStrategy`.

If you have issue with it then you might did not add the base href. Just check `head` section of your `index.html`

```
<base href="/app"/>
```