# how to change after router.navigate and passing paramenter

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I need to pass parameter from a url to another. Suppose to have this url:

```
http://localhost:4200/dev/11
```

and I want go to home and pass parameters and so the url and Ido in my angular

```
this.router.navigate(['/products'], { queryParams: { order: 'popular' } });
```

The problem is that the url became `http://localhost:4200/products?order=popular`, but I want hide parameter and show only the url `http://localhost:4200/products`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Router: How to not display parameters in the url bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377565/angular-4-router-how-to-not-display-parameters-in-the-url-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/products',{id:1}]);
```

OR

```
this.router.navigate(['/products', {order: 'popular'}]);
```

Comment: I need to pass parameter to these url!

Comment: @Doflamingo19 , Instead of id & 1 please pass your queryString name and parameter

Comment: @SanjayKatiyar but this solution does't result expected by OP

Comment: i need to hide parameter in the url I don't want see /products?order=popular in the url

Comment: @Doflamingo19 you want to url similar like this. e.g. http://localhost:4200/products

Answer (score 0):

To send params along with routing you need to try this -

```
this.router.navigate(['/products', yourParmas]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/products/' + yourParmas);
```

For more information refer official documentation -

- https://angular.io/guide/router